# Chaining cron scripts to get around 30-second runtime limit

Tags: php, cron, hosting

I have a infrequent custom sitemap generator cron script I need to run on a site currently sitting on a HostGator shared server. The generator script is written in PHP, and executed with the following cron command:

php public_html/mysite.com/core/update.php > update.log

The generation process involves calling an internal API and doing distance calculations based on the result, so the script generally needs 5-10 minutes to run. The hardcoded PHP runtime limit is 30 seconds for HostGator's shared servers.

Is there any way I can have my script break itself down into smaller processes? Does anyone know if transcoding it into Perl or Python would get around the 30-second limit?

Comment: breaking your hots terms and conditions is never a good idea, if you need such resources looks like its time for your own server.

Comment: @MarathonStudios - HostGator doesn't allow changing the max_execution_time. If you want some help trying to figure out how to break the script into smaller ones (or perhaps optimize it), would you mind posting the script?

Comment: @Francois what about set_time_limit() ?

Comment: Is there a way to mark items as done, so if the script dies, you can start it again and have it pick up where you left off? Maybe something that selects all items last updated before today or something like that?

Comment: 0xAli - I posted that as an answer earlier and ended up deleting it once I realized that HostGator clearly statement that you can't change the time limit. That "may" work but even if it did, that would be a violation of the terms of use.

Comment: The script involves the following:

1) Retrieve list of results from an internal API
2) Use the Haversine formula to calculate the nearby results for a list of locations
3) Create result pages for each location, write the data to the sitemap

I could break it up by state, but some states take only seconds (few results) while others take much longer - it's impossible to predict beforehand, which is why I'm having trouble chunking it.

Comment: @AndrewR, I could try that, but as I'm writing files it's a bit trickier to find out where I left off as the last one is usually unfinished - maybe the best thing is to just overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 2):

putting this

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

inside a function or loop where your code spends most of its time should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try forking. You would need to make sure each fork could perform it's work and create a new fork within 30 seconds. Since a fork is a copy of the running process, you retain all the data you've pulled so far.

Alternatively, use multi-curl to blast your server with many requests at once and complete the entire process in under 30 seconds. You would need to divide the work appropriately of course.

Comment: Can I code a forking program using PHP or Python? If so, how?

Comment: In php use the pctl functions. Of course, I hope your host has pctl functions enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php